# Autoplay mp3 at the opening of the page web react.js

Tags: reactjs, audio, gatsby, autoplay

I wish that when the page opens, a music automatically starts playing

```
const Index = ({ data }) => {
return (

  <audio
    autoPlay="autoPlay"
    href="audio_tag"
    loop
    src={data.audio.publicURL}
    type="audio/mpeg"
    controls
  ></audio>
}
```

The music does not start when the page opens because of the loading time of the music.
How can I bypass the music loading time?

Answer (score 2):

> The music does not start when the page opens because of the loading time of the music.

No, the music doesn't start because the browser doesn't let it.

Autoplay of audio is disabled in most any current browser, for most pages.

See also:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_278v_plodvgtXSgnEJ0yjZJLg14Ogf-ekAFNymAJoU/edit

Comment: so there's no way to get around this restriction with React?

Comment: Nope.  It doesn't have anything to do with React, it's a browser restriction.